# Lotus Notes Views are not showing up in the web browser

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We have a legacy Lotus Notes application that we want to see if we can make an improvement, first by making a test environment for this application. Currently the application is located on the main server and being replicated every 15 minutes to the web server. The replica on the web server has different forms and views since they are adjusted to display the information on the web browser (in my understanding)

I have made a new copy of the application that is on the main server without any problem. I had some problem replicating it to the web server since I do not understand what will happen to those element design that are not being used in the application on the web server. So what I did was replicating the application from the main server to the web server, then deleted all the design elements on the web test then copy all the design elements from the production environment to the web test.

By doing that I was able to get into the login page then log in. After I login, the frameset that suppose to display the default view giving this error message 'HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note'. First of all, I thought this is normal since I could not find the view in the database and that confused me since the live system works without that view present on the database BUT when I tried to access a view that I know present on the database, I still get the same error.

So after all that I opened the web test application on a Lotus Notes client. I can open the views that are exist. Now at this point there are 2 things that I am very frustrated about:

1. The live system works even when the code specifically mentions views that I cannot find from the Domino Designer. It just does not make any sense
2. As a test I created a 'Test' view on the web test application. Basically I just told it to fetch one of the form called 'WORec' that contains Work Order information. Into my surprise, the view opens up on the web browser but shows no result, which frustrates me even more since the view 'WOByName' gets all the Work Orders just fine. These 2 views have the same selection formula, so I really do not understand why 1 view is able to show data where the other does not. Moreover if I tell the test view to fetch all the documents in the database it only fetch those documents that are not 'WORec' form

I know this is long but if I can get some pointers on what I am doing wrong here. I am just trying to create a test environment. Unfortunately I never dealt with Domino web application or a replication that completely has different element design.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the test view.

When you created the view, you need to first verify it is a Public view. Private views or Shared Private on First Use (SPOFU) views are not what you want here.

also, verify the name and alias of the view is unique to your database.

Next, verify your selection formula is correct.

use formula, instead of simple so you can actually see the formula. e.g.

SELECT @UpperCase(Form) = "WOREC"

Refresh your view designer (F9) - do you see your records coming through?

also, make sure the view is not hidden from Web clients... you will see this in the designer client, when looking at a list of views - a column indicating whether or not it is hidden from web clients, note clients, mobile clients, etc.

if not, open one of the documents up. Show properties, verify the form property in the box (2nd tab), matches the value "WORec". If not, correct your view selection with the correct form name spelling.

Next, you need to make sure you are allowed to view this from the web.
Open the Access Control List (ACL) and add "anonymous" as reader or above.

Open the view in Designer, and Preview it in web browser.

As for the "Couldn't find design note" message - that's not good. You definitely are missing design elements. Whether this is due to a selective replication formula issue, or acl issue, or whatever, is hard to tell. But if you have a Notes thick client and a separate web version, I would recommend different databases (or master templates) and not trying to use selective replication to handle that sort of thing.

Comment: When you say 'Public' than means 'Shared' right? I do not find a 'Public' option when creating a new view.

Comment: I tried to create a new 'Shared' view with the formula you mentioned above, refreshed it the Designer, but still no records. This is very odd, I opened 'WOByName' view that looks for the same form in the Designer and it got records

Comment: yes, I meant shared. Can you check the security tab on the WOByName view? (alt-enter to open properties, far right tab). What does this look like? Also, you might take another look at the designer help on views, in case you missed something subtle. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_OVERVIEW_OF_FEATURES_TO_AVOID_9010_OVER.html

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you replicated the database then deleted all design elements and manually replaced them by copying from the production web replica.  Instead, you should have made a template from the production web database (by doing a design-only copy), and then you should have used the 'Replace Design' feature to update the test web database from that template.

As an aside: an application built the way you describe (two replicas on separate servers, each with a different set of design elements) is a pretty bad implementation.  It may have been done in the very early days of Domino, before the "Hide from Notes client" and "Hide from Web" properties were available at the design element level.  Or it may have been done deliberately for "security purposes" (which I put in quotes because relying on Domino design element to enforce security on a Domino web application doesn't really make the application any more secure).  You may be stuck with this... but you may not be.  So before you try to improve or enhance this application, I think you should look into using the "Hide from... " properties on the design elements.

On the other hand, if you stick with the current design, I do want to mention that you're going to need to make sure the ACL settings and selective replication settings on your main and web test replicas match the ACL selective replications settings on the corresponding production replicas.  Otherwise, you'll end up with a jumble of design elements when the test databases replicate across servers.

Comment: Your comment on the first paragraph is pretty close to what I did but let me just make it clearer here.

Comment: Your comment on the first paragraph is pretty close to what I did but let me just make it clearer here. We have 1 db on the main server and its replica on the web server. The db on the main server is being accessed by users in the home office through Notes client. The replica on the web server is being used only to display the data that are modified by the user in the office. Now the db and its replica have different design elements, though they have some forms with the same name but they look different which I believe because one is designed for Notes client and one for the web browser

Comment: The problem is I don't understand how that is possible. Shouldn't a db have the same design element when it's being replicated. With that in mind I am confused on how to create the test system. To create the test on the main server, I just use 'New Copy' with Copy design and ACL only which has been working fine as a test system. But if I create a replica from that test system to the web server, again all the design elements are not designed for web viewing. So just like you said, I deleted all the design elements from the replica and copy all the design elements from the production replica db

Comment: I was thinking to create a new copy from the replica production db but then that means the new copy will have a different replica ID from the test db that is on the main server, right? My goal is I would like to have a test system that imitates our current application. Am I making sense here?

Comment: RE "I don't understand how that is possible".  It is not normal, but it can be done.  Typically it is done by manually changing the design elements in one of the replicas, and then setting the ACL very carefully so that design changes do not replicate. I.e., the servers grant each other only Editor access, so they cannot change each other's designs.  (It can also be done with selective replication options, but those are evil and I never ever recommend using them.)

Comment: If you use "New Copy" instead of "New Replica" it is then possible to change the replica ID of the copy to make it match the original again.  There are free tools that can do that, which you can probably find with a simple google search.  You need Manager rights to do it, and you also need the right to create replicas on the server that hosts the database.  But you shouldn't need to do it.  The replace design technique with careful managemnet of the ACLs as described above is a better idea.

Comment: But if there are design elements that have the protection flag set, so that a Replace Design operation ignores them, then the New Copy option may be your best bet.  The issue here really is understanding how it was done in the first place, in detail, in order to understand how to duplicate it properly.

Comment: may I ask what is the point of doing a new copy 'Design and ACL only' then do 'Replace Design' afterwards? I mean the new copy already have the latest design elements right?

Comment: also if I follow your very first comment. Then I create a new copy of the web db (design only) then what do I need to do to make that db is a replica of my test db on the main server?

Comment: In production, you have two replicas with different designs.  Let's assume that the filenames are main.nsf and web.nsf.  Start by making a new copy of main.nsf w/design and ACL only and call this main2.nsf.  Now you want to create web2.nsf, but it must have the same replica ID as main2.nsf.  So make a new replica of main2.nsf and call it web2.nsf.  It has the correct replica ID, but it still has the design from main.nsf.  So now make a template from web.nsf and use that template to replace design of web2.nsf.  Now web2.nsf has design from web.nsf.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a new copy of the Notes Database that is on your web server to your test server.
try to open in with your browser and check that all is OK.
open this copy in designer and check that it contains the views that you didn't see previously on test.

I'm not sure that you have really 2 different designs (one for webser different from the one of your main server) so:
- on the main server: open the File/Replication/Option for this application. In advanced, check  When web server receives from .... if the design elements is checked.
if not it makes sense that there are TWO different design versions.
Maybe the view you didn't find (on the web server) restricts use? to check this:
- In the view (on the main server) check in the properties of the view the tab with a key "all readers and above". If it's uncheck THIS is the reason why they don't exist on the web server AND that you don't see them in the designer:
If your don't have the role or are not the person which can "who may use this view" you don't see the view and can't copy it.
To correct this simply enter the ACL (file/Application/Access Control) and grant you the corresponding role.
I hope I helped

Comment: I checked on the production db, on the Advanced tab, it says. Receive only a subset of information from other replicas When computer 'Main server', Receivers from '-Any Server-. None of the checkboxes are checked

Comment: On the production web db (the replica). On the Advanced tab I see, Receive only a subset of information from other replicas When computer 'Web Server', Receives from '-Any Server-', Documents by selection formula is checked, Receive these elements from other replica 'Deletions'

Comment: When I looked at my test db (new copy) from the db on the main server. The Basics tab on the Replication option is grayed out. Really don't know why.

Comment: That probably indicates that you don't have Manager rights to the database.

Comment: I just checked the ACL. I have a Manager rights and included in all the Roles

Comment: ""None of the checkboxes are checked" ==> You really have TWO different design version! I agree with what other have said: it's far a best practice and should be avoid, but except if a (good) dev can work on this and merge the 2 design, you will have to live with this... so let's go!(see later comment)

Comment: The Basics tab on the Replication option is grayed out=> not a problem ignore this the replication setting for this is in connection doc in the NAB (names&adddrss book=names.nsf)

Comment: concerning your Test' view on the web test application. That should display same as 'WOByName'.<br>
Please check in your test view properties if is checked "show responses document in a hierachy" and make in like in WOByName

Comment: Alternatively check if WOByName has a column "Show response only".